# Unique situation in my career and decision making

Tags: job-offer, new-job

My scenario.

I worked with a company (A) for almost a year. While hunting for a job in my favorite field , I applied to another position (more responsibility, tasks and higher level job) in same company (A) and got the job after they denied me the first time.

While in the process of networking and sending emails to hiring managers that I am good candidate, I also applied to company B.

I did not receive any offer letters from current company(A). Company A considers it a inner transfer despite the job being in a different department with more responsibility, tasks and higher level job and should have a pay raise. While in the process of transfering and waiting and waiting with my current company and setting up a transfer date...I got a job offer from  company (B). I accepted the job offer from company B because of the higher salary and it is near my house. I am currently waiting to set up my start date. Since it was the beginning of the hiring process in company B and not knowing my start date there, I started my job in the current company (company A) in a different department...without signing or accepting a job offer. The process of company B is in background check and trying to figure out the start date and can take another two weeks

How should I cope with this situation in the best way possible?

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: When you get a start date you give your notice.

Comment: Sorry, but in its current state this question is asking for advice and is not a  practical answerable question.

Comment: A clearer question to answer may help.  Are you looking for assistance with quitting the old job?  Starting the new one? Handling the transition?  etc etc.

Answer (score 2):

> How should I cope with this situation in the best way possible?

There's nothing unique here.

When you get your formal, written offer from Company B including the start date, you give your notice to Company A and serve out the notice period.

This is the same as you would handle the case where you didn't have an internal transfer.

You can't really back out of the internal transfer now - it's too late. It's just a matter of timing.

Just handle it normally, in the normal manner, without regard to the fact that you are now in a new department and role.

Answer (score 0):

Talk with your manager or direct boss and be frank about your situation.  **Nobody** (with a minimum of common sense) will ask you to stay for a small salary.

However, you must bet to stay in A or B, **you can't wait for the last day** to quit your current job.  Also, its not rare to find yourself returning back to a company that you already worked.

Also, if B company took so much time then it could be a proof that you aren't the first candidate but the second or third alternative.